# Preposition and Tense

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verb-forms

In today's exam, I had few grammar questions. I am doubtful in two questions. Please check my answers and correct the mistakes, if any.

1.Fill with suitable prepositions.

> There lived _ _ _ _ _ a forest a pride of lions _ _ _ _ _ several cubs

I wrote

> There lived in a forest a pride of lions with several cubs

2.Fill with suitable verb forms.

> Yarmuk _ _ _ _ French for the last 5 years but now he _ _ _ _ German.(learn)

I wrote

> Yarmuk has been learning French for the last 5 years but now he is learning German.

Am I right?

Comment: One question per question, please. The two parts of your question are completely unrelated.

Comment: @200_success I would make two threads. But some people will still blame me that I am spamming to get attention and they will advise to ask me it in the same thread. I have experienced that in another community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. I would say "Yarmuk **had** been learning French for the last 5 years but now he is learning German."

Though the only real difference between the word choice of mohamed's answer and mine is the intent of the sentence.

In mohamed's version, Yarmuk has learned French in it's entirety, and he is now in the process of learning German.

In mine, Yarmuk has switched from learning French to learning German.

Who's right and who's wrong is ultimately up to the writer of the test.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, correct answer.

2) No, it should be :

Yarmuk `learned` French for the last 5 years but now he is learning German.

Because he learned French in the past but now, this verb is finished.

> But now is learning German now.

This indicates that other verb (learning French) is completely finished, so, you should choose the past simple tense "`learned`".

But, if the other verb has happened in the past and is still ongoing, then, choose the present perfect "`has learned`".

Comment: Don't mention it.